# How "right to food" is implemented in Western countries?

Tags: human-rights, food

Some sources (such as Amnesty International) [claim](http://www.refworld.org/cgi-bin/texis/vtx/rwmain?page=topic&tocid=4565c2252f&toid=4565c25f3dd&publisher=AMNESTY&type=&coi=&docid=4a7948a52&skip=0) that denial of "right to food" in North Korea violates internationally agreed right to life.

I wonder whether Western countries guarantee right to food?

If somebody has no food to eat, can they receive necessary food for free from the state (as opposed to non-governmental/religious organizations)?

Comment: The thing you need to realize that in the west the poor have cell phones, vehicles, lots of cloths and some disposable money.  In the east the poor are lucky to have more than one set of clothing and have none of the others with out scrounging.  You can not really compare the1st world west to 2nd and 3rd world east

Comment: Your question, as currently written suffers from a fallacy reffered to as [Begging the Question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question)  You have a premise that you incorrectly equate from a governement actively preventing its people from having **ANY** food to the right to free(as in beer) food for everyone.

Comment: Can you at least cite the *some sources* that you refer to?

Comment: @Chad if somebody has no money to buy food, then they have no any food, and if they just take it, they will be punished by the government. Of course if the government does not provide some money to buy food.

Comment: @JNK Amnesty International, for example: http://www.refworld.org/cgi-bin/texis/vtx/rwmain?page=topic&tocid=4565c2252f&toid=4565c25f3dd&publisher=AMNESTY&type=&coi=&docid=4a7948a52&skip=0

Comment: @Anixx _ I am not trying to argue the logic of your arguement. Just saying that as written your question suffers from logical fallacy.  Rewrite the question to focus on the rights of the poor to have food given to them if you wish but you need to remove the reference to the rights being violated by NK when you do so.

Comment: "Some sources claim that denial of "right to food" in North Korea violates internationally agreed right to life." - please provide the cite and the source of such claim.

Comment: Having said that, pretty much 100% of Western welfare systems are based on (though not always codified in law) "right to food" concept.

Comment: @DVK seel the above link to Amnesty International.

Comment: @DVK I am interested in details. Also in differences between Europe and the US.

Comment: @Anixx - We are interested in answering well written quesitons.  You resist our efforts to help you improve your question makes us loath to bother answering your poorly asked question.

Comment: @Anixx - Please add the AI reference to the post. That's a valid one.

Comment: food stamps.  $200 per month

Comment: Have you ever heard the expression "the right to swing your fist ends at my face?"  you have a right to food, but that does not nullify others' property rights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Supplemental Nutrition Assistance Program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplemental_Nutrition_Assistance_Program) (SNAP), formerly known as the **Food Stamp** program, provides financial assistance for purchasing food to low- and no-income people living in the U.S. It is a federal aid program, administered by the U.S. Department of Agriculture, though benefits are distributed by individual U.S. states.

http://www.fns.usda.gov/snap/applicant_recipients/eligibility.htm lists eligibility requirements.

Anyone with less than $threshold of assets and income qualifies, with one caveat: if you're an unemployed able-bodied adult (not disabled, child or senior), you must qualify also for "able-bodied adults between 16 and 60 must register for work, accept suitable employment, and take part in an employment and training program to which they are referred by the local office". Basically, if you look to the SS office like you are looking for work with any convincing degree of effort, you pass.

As far as I know, most western countries have an equivalent, frequently with LESS of eligibility requirements (e.g. you don't even need to show effort to find work for "Income Support" in UK - they didn't have Food Stamps per se till ~2012 or so, just cash help).

Comment: And the downvote is because?

Comment: The right to food is also referenced in the `International Covenant on Economic, Social and Cultural Rights` which most countries have signed off on at this point.

Comment: @JNK - make that an answer; although the question title is about implementation, not theoretical basis.

Comment: That's why it's not an answer :)  Just gives some perspective on the scale of food welfare programs which are pretty much universal.

Comment: You have to show effort in finding a job in order to qualify for income support in the UK, no matter what some tabloids do say. The requirements are minimal, I admit, it used to be you had to apply to a job a week. Not doing this or not attending interviews etc could lose you that benefit.

Comment: @Ben actually, people that I know who have broken the terms of their JSA (for the benefit of non-UK readers: Jobseeker's Allowance is the income support Ben mentioned, as its name suggests you need to be actively looking for work in order to qualify for it) agreement still have access to *some* funds. It's an even smaller amount than the JSA, but the government won't just leave people to starve.

Comment: I raise a skeptical eyebrow that foodstamps is a *right*, per se.  I think it is appropriate, and in most cases a legitimate use of government resources, but a right?  Rights are passive in nature where the government is obligated to *not* do something, like punish people for expressing themselves, force them to worship a certain god, etc.  I have a difficult time reconciling a "right" to food with a governmental obligation to do anything but govern.

Comment: @Jeremy Holovacs seems it is a pecularity of your perception. Nearly all countries guarantee first medical aid (not providing it considered a homicide), some countries guarantee shelter adn employment as fundamental rights (as all Socialist countries did). Recently some countries declared Internet access as fundamental right and provide free internet link to anybody.

Comment: @Anixx, it may well indeed be an idiosyncrasy of mine, still... isn't a right more than a reasonable expectation?  You speak of Socialist countries guaranteeing employment, where socialist countries like France, Spain, and Greece have unemployment above 10%.  Doesn't this suggest we're being a little cavalier tossing around a term like "right"?

Comment: @Jeremy Holovacs France, Spain and Greece never been socialist countries.

Comment: @Anixx, what are you considering a socialist country then?  I had assumed you were talking political party/ leadership based.

Comment: @Jeremy Holovacs, the USSR and its allies. All these countries had right to job and right to shelter in constitution.

Comment: What if disabled? If disabled, you are entitled for pension or what?